# Performance issue using AntiSamy filter in Spring MVC

Tags: java, performance, spring-mvc, antisamy

In my Web application project we are using AntiSamy filter to validate the user input, after including it the performance of the application is too slow to load a screen.. I believe it is because of using Antisamy. Please let me know if there any ways to over come this performance issue.

Thanks.

Comment: "I believe it is because of using Antisamy." Have you tried (if possible) to disable the validation, and does that lead to a significant speedup - solving the performance issue?

Comment: Yes i did try, the performace did improve but we cant compromise the security. Is there any way to overcome this issue? Or is there anyother tool that i can use instead of Antisamy>

Comment: Well, what are you using AntiSamy for? I can't recommend how to do things differently if I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I am using it to sanitize the data that is coming to the application.

Comment: Data like user entered values and files for a retail application to prevent cross site scripting

Comment: The files, you'll obviously have to check those. But (and I might be getting your definition of "values" wrong)... do you really need to validate if things like numbers don't contain evil XSS? Additionally, just how much of a slowdown is antisamy adding to your application?

Comment: With Antisamy the loading time gets doubled.